# How to fix the issue: "localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500"

Tags: php, localhost

I have a PHP script which connects to a database setup up with MAMP.

However it doesn't seem to be able to connect to the database. Every time I tried, it has failed with the message:

> This page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this
>   request. HTTP ERROR 500

```
<?php 

        $host = "localhost:8889";
        $dbusername = "root";
        $dbpassword = "root";
        $dbname = "HMSDb"; 

        //Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli_connect($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM login;";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($resultCheck > 0) {
            while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo $row['username'] . "<br>";
        } else {
                echo "Fail";
        }

?>
```

Comment: you are probably getting database errors. Your code is not checking if the connection or query was successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTP `500` code stands for a server error. As said Tim, check your server logs.

By the way, you should fix your `if` statement by adding the missing curly braket `{`:

```
if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['username'] . "<br>";
    }
} // <- missing curly bracket
else {
    echo "Fail";
}
```

Comment: That missing bracket is a likely cause of the 500 error

Answer (score 2):

The best place to start would be to check your server logs.

Their location depends on what your system is and how you installed your web server. Google should help to find them, `error_log` is what you seek.

But this particular problem may be caused by your `$host` including the port. If you need to specify a non-default port, add it as per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) as an additional argument to `mysqli_connect()` after `$dbname`.

Edit:

After a live test, my `error_log` indicates the cause is the use of the `new` keyword. Remove it from:

`$conn = new mysqli_connect($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);`

or use `mysqli();` instead. `mysqli_connect()` is a function, not a class, and as such it cannot be instantiated with the `new` keyword.

The error: `Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli_connect' not found in /index.php`

Of course, fix your missing bracket too as Amessihel mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work. If it rewrite like

```
     $host = "localhost";
        $dbusername = "root"; // username
        $dbpassword = "password"; // your password
        $dbname = "test";  // dbname

        //Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM fruit";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        echo "<ul>";
        if ($resultCheck > 0) {
            while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                //echo $row['username'] . "<br>";
                echo "<li> A ".$rows["name"]." is ".$rows["color"]. "</li>";

        }
        } else {
                echo "Fail";
        }
    echo "</ul>";
```

I test the code with my table . Please make respective changes in your code..

All the best

Anes

Comment: You should explain what changes you made.